# Question on comparing two fields in Access

Tags: database-design, table, functions

I'm not sure if the title is fitting as I am not 100% sure if what I am doing is correct but here goes.

Here is my enrolment table,

[image]

I have added a field called pass/fail as you can see which is a calculated field that holds the following expression. the field displays passed if the overall grade is over 40%.

[image]

What I wish to is in my student table shown below create the same field Pass/Fail that checks the student has passed or failed depending on all of his modules.

[image]

Let me explain further, as you can see within the enrolment table the student ID is mentioned twice for each student however the module number is different as each student has taken two modules. i want the field within the student table to display passed only if the student has passed all modules.

If anyone can give some advice on how I could possibly go about doing this I would be most grateful. Preferably I would like to do this with the use of an `IFf` statement however I'm open to other options.

I have included an image of my relationships if that would help.

[image]

Comment: That sounds like it would be a aggregate function, but I am not sure if you can do that at the table level, I know that you can get those results by building a query on the table and then using the query as a source for a view, form, or additional select.